# Find assembly instruction by C++ regex

Tags: regex

I have a text of disassembly and I want to find out all the instructions and their addresses.

The assembly has contents like

```
00000000: ae ee    move $1, $2
00000004: c1       add  $2, $2, $3
00000006: a2 aa e3 addi $1, $2, $4
```

Each line can be divided in three groups

- the address, a 8-digits in hexidecimal, followed by a colon (`[a-f0-9]{8}:`)
- the machine code, a series of 2-digits in hexidecimal (`[a-f0-9]\s+`)
- the instruction (`(.*)`)

I wonder if it's possible to match "a series of 2-digits in hexidecimal"? so I can find those instructions from the third group in a pattern like

`([a-f0-9]{8}):\s+(blabla)(.*)`

Comment: That's surely possible, but whatever you want to do with the results is probably achieved in an easier way by using an assembly file parser.

Comment: Im not sure if its the best way to accomplish that. Instructions can have multiple opcode. Example with x86 cpu, you can find depending of the context : prefix, opcode, modrm/sib, displacement .... however, address of instruction can be larger than 8 bits. You need to take all in consideration.

Comment: Like this? `^([a-f0-9]{8}):((?:\s+[a-f0-9]{2})+)\b\s+(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/K12K85/1

Comment: Let's hope you don't have any opcodes like `bf` (branch if false), which look like hexadecimal values.